# Authority for Batch update the sms content

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to update the sms body by `applyBatch` method. I would like to know which `AUTHORITY` should I use in the following code. How can I use for `applyBatch()` first param for sms?

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    String where = "_id = ?";

    for(String k : keys) {
        String body = map.get(k);
        ops.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(mSmsinboxQueryUri).withSelection(where, new String[]{k})
                        .withValue(Telephony.Sms.BODY, body)
                        .withYieldAllowed(true)
                        .build());
    }

    try {
        getContentResolver().
                applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123973/2652368) post it is `"sms"`

also in android source code in this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/android-7.1.1_r38/src/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsSmsProvider.java) defines authority like this

`private static final String AUTHORITY = "mms-sms";`

so your operation should be:

```
getContentResolver().applyBatch("sms",ops); // if it throws exception use "mms-sms"
```

works fine for me.